# python matplotlib: onclick does not work, please show me why and how to pause and resume the animation,

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, matplotlib-animation

I would like to pause and resume animation when click on figure by mouse, but it does not work, please help me to fix it, thank you,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(10, 110)

pause = False
def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

line, = ax.plot([], [])

ax.set_ylim(0, 120)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)


def runData(i):

    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])

    return line

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)    

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, runData, frames=len(x), blit=False, interval=10, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify `pause` in the `runData()`. Here is it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(10, 110)

pause = False
def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
line, = ax.plot([], [])
ax.set_ylim(0, 120)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)

def runData(i):
    if not pause:
        line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
        return line

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, runData, frames=len(x), blit=False, interval=10, repeat=True)
fig.show()
```